# How to create package file similar to Logic or Final Cut project

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, package

I am trying to create a file in OS X that is essentially a package that has files in it, similar to how a Logic project is a single file but contains all of the audio files within it (when you right-click the file it has the "Show Package Contents" option).

Doing this in Swift would be great, but also curious just in general how this is done? I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a "Document Package" type. Basically these "packages" are just a directory with a file extension applied that tells macOS to display them as a package. As long as you setup the type in your applications `Info.plist` then you shouldn't need any special API's to create the packages (though apple does have some helper APIs if you want to use them).

For complete documentation on defining a new "Document Package" type and some links to some helper API's see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting stumped with how Apple registered the package and extension, but the Info.plist explains that perfectly.