# How to save files to a document package with a custom extension in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilewrapper

I need to bundle multiple files created within my OSX app into a document package with a custom file extension that can be opened later for modification/playback/etc.

For example, I want to save the following files:

- quicktime.mov
- text.txt
- info.plist

to file a called **mybundle.cust**

I essentially want to do what this guy is doing here:

[How to create package file similar to Logic or Final Cut project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892572/how-to-create-package-file-similar-to-logic-or-final-cut-project)

but I'm new to Swift and have struggled to find sample code addressing this. Can someone give me a bare-bones headstart?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation linked in that answer?